# Finding IP Addresses from Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, ip-address, hostname

I am trying to display a list of all devices connected to the current wifi network.

The problem I am facing, is when I try the below code (using a DNS Lookup) on Java, I see several devices. (Which is good); but it doesn't work on my android device or emulator.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am developing on a Lolipop Phone, that is connected to WiFi. The only IP address that is found, is the local host.

```
byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 254; i++)
                {
                    ip[3] = (byte)i;
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                    if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName() ) )
                    {
                        // machine is known in a DNS lookup
                           AvailableHostList.add(address);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that on some carriers, Verizon for instance, wireless smartphones only use IPv6 (more than 18 quintillion addresses per subnet). I don't believe any of the carriers will let you discover other devices on your network since this is a security breach. I'm not sure how they handle Wi-Fi, but I doubt you can do this on the carrier's network.

Comment: Right, I am trying to do this on Wi-Fi (not on the carrier networks).. There are other apps that do this, so I know it is possible.

Comment: OK. Also remember, IPv4 subnets can have a variable number of addresses, and IPv6 subnets have such a large number that it will take you many thousands of years to check them all by brute force. You should check the subnet size in IPv4 so that you can try to check, but I have seen people use 10.0.0.0/8 which will be impractical, and commercial Wi-Fi can prevent you from checking any other addresses on your subnet.

Comment: But in that case, wouldnt it not work in Java?

Comment: It depends on the environment as to whether it works or not. Home Wi-Fi for IPv4 may be pretty simple unless it has a large subnet configured. IPv6 should use some of the protocols to discover neighbors instead of a brute force method. Even on home Wi-Fi, but especially on commercial, you can be locked out of discovering any neighbors since everything must go through the router, and the router can lie to you. It's not the simple problem that it may seem; things that work on most basically configured home Wi-Fi may just not work on proper Wi-Fi implementations.

Comment: Assume it is your network. If I can scan it find on a pc, then I should be able to do it fine on Android. Other android apps can do this fine, so Im trying to see how it can be done. I have found some materials in NetworkInterface, so I think the answer will ultimately be there

Answer (score 0):

All, I finally got this to work.
The issue was that I wasn't able to get the IP Address properly.  So I first I found my local IP.. below...

```
                 for (NetworkInterface intf : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()))
                 {
                     for (InetAddress addr : Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses()))
                     {

                         if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress())
                         {
                             int ipAddress = 0;
                             ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
                             ip = "IP:   " + String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
                             localIP =  String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

localIP is the IP Address in a String format. (1.2.3.4).. So then I just made a byte with the IP Address, and scanned each one.. I saved each IP that was in the DNS Server, or had a response, to an ArrayList.

```
byte[] ip = new byte[4];
    int ipInt = parseNumericAddress(localIP);
    ip[3] = (byte) (ipInt & 0xFF);
    ip[2] = (byte) ((ipInt >> 8) & 0xFF);
    ip[1] = (byte) ((ipInt >> 16) & 0xFF);
    ip[0] = (byte) ((ipInt >> 24) & 0xFF);


              progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
              for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
                {
                    progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    ip[3] = (byte)i;

                    try {
                         InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                        if (address.isReachable(100))
                        {
                            // machine is turned on and can be pinged
                            System.out.println("***Can Be Pinged*** Host Name " + address.getHostName() + address.getAddress().toString());
                            AvailableHostList.add(address.getHostName().toString());
                        }
                        else 
                        if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName() ) )
                        {
                            // machine is known in a DNS lookup
                            System.out.println("***Can Be Found in DNS Look Up*** HostName:" + address.getHostName() + "Address: "+address.getAddress().toString());
                            AvailableHostList.add(address.getHostName().toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Can Not Be Found" + address.toString());

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```